# ASP.NET MVC loading partial view in popup

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I load a page or a partial view in the popup window in jQuery?  I am using jQuery popup but it is not loading with JavaScript.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To load it into a placeholder:

```
$("#idOfPartialViewContainerOnPage").load("/ControllerName/PartialViewName");
```

Where the Action looks something like:

```
public ActionResult PartialViewName() 
{
    return PartialView(GetModelForMyPartialView());
}
```

To make it a popup window, use something like jQuery UI dialog:

```
var ph = $("#idOfPartialViewContainerOnPage");
ph.load("/ControllerName/PartialViewName", function() { 
    ph.dialog({
        // set dialog options here
    });
});
```